# Rspec Test showing NoMethodError: undefined method `response_code' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am writing a Rspec test for formData post method. My Rpsec test is as below:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ApplicationController do
  include Rack::Test::Methods
  before do
    @tempfile = File.new('./image.png')
    @file = Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(@tempfile, 'image/png', true)
  end

  it 'can upload a file' do
    params = {
      files: [@file],
      phone: '000000000',
      email: 'example@gmail.com',
      name: 'example',
    }
    post '/form-data/post', params
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

As I run the test, the terminal shows `Completed 200 OK` but immediately gets the error.

```
Failure/Error: assert_response :success
     
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `response_code' for nil:NilClass
```

Why is the response showing nil even though the post method went well and shows `Completed 200 OK`?
Hoping for your answers.

Comment: after a long search and test, I found the answer. I just need to the mention `last_response` instead of `response`.  
```expect(last_response.status).to eq(200)```
 by writing this, I solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

after a long search and test, I found the answer. I just need to the mention `last_response` instead of `response`.
By writing the following exceptation, I solved my problem.

```
expect(last_response.status).to eq(200)
```